# How to create drop down information box in C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

I want to make a button that can drop down a multi-line label or form which contains help documentation for the user.

I have searched and I can't find anything that is for C# Winforms. Do any free controls out there exist for this or will I have to create it myself?
Many thanks,
Richard

Comment: This seems a bit unclear... you want a button to open a form containing help documentation?

Comment: Do you mean a tooltip?

Comment: I dont want to open a new form window but rather a box on the current form containing documentation.

Comment: I think you do mean a `tooltip`.  So when you hover over something it will show you some help documentation on that item?

Comment: Perhaps I do mean a tooltip. I'll have a look into it and see what ways I can format one.

Comment: Evan, Yes but I'd like to trigger it when pressing a button.

Comment: Both answers below provide good examples, however I agree that using a button click to show a tooltip is bad UX.

Comment: On the contrary, for what I am trying to do it makes perfect sense to have drop down text on a button click. Thank you both for your responses below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ToolStripControlHost and ToolStripDropDown controls can provide this for you:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var helpInfo = new StringBuilder();
  helpInfo.AppendLine("This is line one.");
  helpInfo.AppendLine("This is line two.");
  var textHelp = new TextBox() { Multiline = true,
                                 ReadOnly = true,
                                 Text = helpInfo.ToString(),
                                 MinimumSize = new Size(100, 100)
                                };
  var toolHost = new ToolStripControlHost(textHelp);
  toolHost.Margin = new Padding(0);
  var toolDrop = new ToolStripDropDown();
  toolDrop.Padding = new Padding(0);
  toolDrop.Items.Add(toolHost);
  toolDrop.Show(button1, button1.Width, 0);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I am after!

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be a bad user experience to see a tooltip on click of a button. However, you can use this if you really want to

```
var b  = new Button();
b.Click += (sender, args) => new ToolTip().Show("Help documentation", b.Parent, new Point(b.Location.X, b.Location.X + 10));
```