# Bring a control to front

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user control that uses a textbox and a list box. List box isn't visible, it only becomes visible when user starts typing or click in text box.

I have added the user control to a group box which is on the form.

Now when the listox becomes visible, it stays inside the group box, and can't see the full height. I wan't it float on top so that i can see the full height.

I have looked around, implemented some solutions but nothing worked for me.

Constructor for the user control

```
namespace YarCustomControl
{
    public partial class YarCustom : TextBox 
    {
        public YarCustom()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _code = "";
            _id = -1;

            //list box handling
            listBox = new ListBox();
            listBox.Visible = false;
            listBox.Font = this.Font;
            listBox.Location = this.Location;
            listBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            listBox.Resize += new EventHandler(listBox_Resize);
            //listBox.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(listBox_SelectedValueChanged);
            listBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(listBox_KeyDown);
            listBox.Click += new EventHandler(listBox_Click);

            //test => no affect on listbox
            this.Controls.Add(listBox);

            listBox.Visible = false;

        }
}
}
```

and the following method makes the listbox visible. Both SetchildIndex (commented and not commented) throw an error

```
private void makeListBoxVisible()
        {
            Form parentForm = (this.FindForm() as Form);

            //parentForm.Controls.SetChildIndex(listBox, 0);
            this.Controls.SetChildIndex(listBox, 0);
            listBox.Visible = true;
            listBox.BringToFront();
        }
```

[image]

What is the best approach for handling something like this?

My environment is VS2010 and WinForms.

Comment: Why not just use a ComboBox, which you seem to be imitating?

Comment: Creating some thing close to what they have currently and are having an issue with.

Comment: You can try it this way: [How to create drop down information box in C# Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289062/719186)

Answer (score 0):

> Now when the listox becomes visible, it stays inside the group box,
>   and can't see the full height. I wan't it float on top so that i can
>   see the full height.

Simply put it directly on the Form.

Comment: Can't. it will replace the current control for which they don't have the source code and are facing certain issues.