# C# Detect if Form is in the "Background" / Invisible (for the User)

Tags: c#, winforms

We have some Forms that have no border / no toolbox (overlays)

Whenever the user clicks somewhere else in the underlaying window, the overlay-form is send to the background (regular non-modal-form behaviour)

Is there an Event for this, so the "overlay" could detect it's visibility change and close itself?

Maybe it can be handled within in resize / paint event, where the "invisibility" can be catched?

---

Background: 
Typical "Select-Or-Create-New" UseCase. Clicking "plus" shows the tiny creation-form. Currently it's "topmost", so the user needs to hit "Escape" to get rid of it. (Else there would be a mess of "background-overlays", hence the question)

Would be more "userfriendly" if a click on something else closes that "tiny form":

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Form.Deactivate?

Comment: @TnTinMn Form.Deactivate!

Comment: Change the pop-up form to `TopLevel = false;` and try using this example: [How to create drop down information box in C# Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289062/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech yes, ofc. its no longer "TopLevel". That was just a workaround to avoid having a lot overlays beeing send to the background whenever the user clicks "somewhere else".

Comment: I think you missed my point.  A pop-up control using a ToolStripControlHost would close the pop-up for you when the user clicks somewhere else.  It also wouldn't deactivate your main form.

Comment: @LarsTech Have to dig into that - but I believe a "Tool-Tip-Based" solution wouldn't allow to show complex forms, where data can be entered, altered and saved. (Except the ToolStripControlHost allows more complex elements to be added to its collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Deactivate` event of the form:

```
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thx, missed the obvious it seems.

Comment: @dognose, this happens, although I have used this event many times (long time ago) I opened a new winform project and looked in the events, because although I knew it was there I didn't remember what was it ;)

Comment: @dognose Instead of `Visible = false;`, you might want to do something like `Opacity = .5;` so that the form can still be seen (and re-activated again, where you would set `Opacity = 1;`)

Comment: Also checked all Events, but after `VisibleChanged` just reacted on `this.visible=x` - I expected `Disabled` to require an explicit setting of  `this.enabled=false` as well :-)

Comment: @RufusL this was only to show the event, and dognose is an experienced programmer as his rep shows, he'll get hang of it. and I actually set visibility because of this:**Is there an Event for this, so the "overlay" could detect it's visibility change and close itself**

Comment: @RufusL No, closing it "on blur" is fine. Can be re-opened with another click on [+]

Comment: Ok, got it! I misunderstood what the window was for.

Comment: @RufusL And I missunderstood your discussion :) For me `Form_deactivate(){ this.close(); }` is perfectly fine - overlay shown on [+], overlay closed "on blur" (so to say) - perfect.